# regex that check the validate of a string

Tags: regex

I m looking a regex that checks if the string is valid or not.

The regex has the following rules :

1. Is not allowed that the string begins with the char `*`
2. The string has to begin with  a char
3. The string could have  a special char after  a normal char(for example: `a**g***`)

Actually  this is my regex :

```
^(?!(\w.*?\\w.*){3}|\w.*? |\*$)\w.*?.*
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: "have to begin with a char" -- everything in a string is a character, so what does that mean?

Comment: May be this: `^\w(?!.*\W\W).*`

Comment: `^(?=\w+.*)$` would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `char`? every character is a char!

If by char, you just mean everything except `*` you can use this: `/^[^\*].*$/`

If by char, you mean any alphanemeric value you can try: `/^\w.*$/`

If by char, you mean just alphabetic charachters: `/^[a-zA-Z].*$/`

Comment: No need to escape `*` inside `[]`